# Django: pagination with prefetch_related

Tags: django, django-orm

I have a model specifications which are divided into categories. For the template, in order to display the category as an header in the table, I make a prefetch_related on the Category like this:

```
categories = Category.objects.distinct().prefetch_related('specifications').filter(filters)
```

Now I can loop over the categories and show the related specifications like:

```
{% for category in categories %}
    <tr>
        <th colspan="7">{{ category.name }} - ({{ category.abbr }})</th>
    </tr>
    {% for specification in category.specifications.all %}
    ...
```

I also want to use the paginator, but now the paginator only counts the categories and not the related specifications. Is it possible to paginate on the specifications with the given query or should I change the query to retrieve all the specifications?

Answer (score 2):

Use [Prefetch](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.Prefetch)

```
categories = Category.objects.distinct().filter(filters)
category_ids = categories.values_list('id', flat=True) # category ids on page
categories = categories.prefetch_related(
    Prefetch(
        'specifications',
        queryset=Specialization.objects.filter(category_id__in=category_ids)
    )
)
```

Here it creates another db request (to fetch category ids) but it will cost less than prefetch all specializations I think. It depends on your data structure but it definitely one of solutions.

Comment: ok this is for a better request against the db, thx. But it does not solve my question. If I have one category with 100 specifications it does not make a pagination.

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to achieve is an anti-pattern of `prefetch_related`. Prefetch is to fetch "all" the related rows, but the use case is to paginate the `specifications`.

Prefetch would be good in cases where the number of related rows per parent row is ~5 (or upto 10, remember that you are wasting DB network bandwidth growing prefetched child rows. So if you are considering pagination, it is best to avoid prefetch)

Note: Child rows = specifications, Parent rows = categories, in your use case.

My answer would be to avoid using prefetch in this case. Just use the following

```
categories = Category.objects.distinct().filter(filters)
--
{% for category in categories %}
<tr>
    <th colspan="7">{{ category.name }} - ({{ category.abbr }})</th>
</tr>
# Use some table lib like django-tables 
...
```

If this is a simple internal project, do go ahead with prefetch, no problems, otherwise you are going to hit DB performance issues.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [django-tables2](https://django-tables2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pages/pagination.html)?

With it you could just simply render the table with something like:

Create a CategoryTable class and add it to your view:

```
class CategoryTable(tables.Table):
    class Meta:
        model = Category


def your_view(request):
    ...
    categories = Category.objects.distinct()
                                 .prefetch_related('specifications')
                                 .filter(filters)
    table = CategoryTable(categories)
    table.paginate(page=request.GET.get("page", 1), per_page=25)
    return render(request, "category_template.html", {"table": table})
```

Then, in your template just put:

```
{% load django_tables2 %}
{% render_table table %}
```